# FileMaker PHP API Connection Issue

Tags: php, api, connection, filemaker

I have recently created a script which should be passed an IP address of the users FM DB Server location, then the script will connect to that server with the given username, password, IP Address and DB Name.

However, no matter what I pass as the IP, it never throws an error.

Is there some form of error handling within the FileMaker PHP API for connection errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you check the HTTP response's status code?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't know how your API is working...

Comment: It's not MY API its FileMaker's API for PHP but I am just utilizing it. As it's not using the HTTP protocol either I don't think I can use fsockopen (and associated functions) to perfrom this action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server that you're making the calls from needs to have curl support - make sure that's enabled. Best bet is to try locally against your FMS box with the test database - once you've got that working then you can try the remote connection.

Answer (score 2):

All the FileMaker API calls return an result object in case of error. You should try this:

Here is an example:

```
$fm = new FileMaker();

// Set 'hostspec' property using setProperty()
$fm->setProperty('database', $fmConfig['db']);
$fm->setProperty('hostspec', $fmConfig['host']);
$fm->setProperty('username', $fmConfig['user']); 
$fm->setProperty('password', $fmConfig['pass']);

$dt = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $myDate);
$freq = $fm->newFindCommand("myTestLayout_1.0") ;
$freq->addFindCriterion("ModificationTimeStamp", ">".$dt);
$result = $freq->execute();
if (FileMaker::isError($result)) {
    $ErrMsg = 'Error code: '.$result->getCode().' Message: '.$result->getMessage();
    throw new Exception ($ErrMsg);  
}
$foundRecords = $result->getRecords();
echo count($foundRecords)." records";
```

Comment: Haha thanks, I can't really remember the problem I had exactly, but I think I sorted it out in my API Interface: https://github.com/DarkMantisCS/FileMaker-PHP-API-Interface if I recall correctly, that is what I was going to be using it for :)